# How to make JS to show different image

Tags: javascript, html

I used that script to show a modal with images, but I want to do that the modal that will pop-up will show the specific image that pressed.

The problem is that the JS is only respond the the first img, but when I add the second img to the script its just wont working... There is any easy way to make the JS work for each img or I need to write and whole script for each img?

```js
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

var img = document.getElementById("myImg");
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img1"); // second img (img1)
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img2"); // second img (img2)

img.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
  modalImg.src = this.src;
}

var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
#myImg {
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

#myImg:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}

.modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
}

.modal-content,
{
  animation-name: zoom;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@keyframes zoom {
  from {
    transform: scale(0)
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1)
  }
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #bbb;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .modal-content {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/150/150" id="myImg">
  <div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <span class="close">
         &times;
      </span>
    <img class="modal-content" id="img1">
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/137/150/150" id="myImg">
  <div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <span class="close">
         &times;
      </span>
    <img class="modal-content" id="img2">
  </div>
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

first, you cannot give the same id to multiple elements in your document. second, when you redeclare the variable named `modalImg` the second time, you are overwriting the value that you put in the variable the first time. third, `getElementById()` will only get reference to one element, but even if it were a function to get multiple elements, you would have to iterate through those elements to set an event listener on each.

Answer (score 0):

Cleaning up the duplicate id's, moving the "close" behavior inline, and (for brevity's sake) taking advantage of auto-wired-up DOM variables (any element with a unique id is available as a variable immediately) I got this:

```js
myImg.onclick = function() {
  myModal.style.display = "block";
  modalImg1.src = this.src;
}
myImg2.onclick = function() {
  myModal2.style.display = "block";
  modalImg2.src = this.src;
}
```

```css
#myImg {
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

#myImg:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}

.modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
}

.modal-content,
{
  animation-name: zoom;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@keyframes zoom {
  from {
    transform: scale(0)
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1)
  }
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #bbb;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .modal-content {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/150/150" id="myImg">
  <div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <span class="close" onclick="myModal.style.display='none'">
         &times;
      </span>
    <img class="modal-content" id="modalImg1">
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/137/150/150" id="myImg2">
  <div id="myModal2" class="modal">
    <span class="close" onclick="myModal2.style.display='none'">
         &times;
      </span>
    <img class="modal-content" id="modalImg2">
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

it better to not have duplicate `id`, I will modify the block html like below

```
<div class="item"> <!-- add class to the block -->
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/150/150" class="thumb">
  <div class="modal">
    <span class="close">
         &times;
      </span>
    <img class="modal-content">
  </div>
</div>
```

so the complete code will be like

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.item').forEach(function(item) {
  var modal = item.querySelector('.modal');
  item.querySelector('.thumb').onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
  }
  item.querySelector('.close').onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
})
```

```css
.thumb{border-radius:5px;cursor:pointer;transition:.3s}
.thumb:hover{opacity:.7}
.modal{display:none;position:fixed;z-index:1;padding-top:100px;left:0;top:0;width:100%;height:100%;overflow:auto;background-color:#000;background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.9)}
.modal-content{margin:auto;display:block;width:80%;max-width:700px}
.modal-content,{animation-name:zoom;animation-duration:.6s}
@keyframes zoom {from{transform:scale(0)}to{transform:scale(1)}}
.close{position:absolute;top:15px;right:35px;color:#f1f1f1;font-size:40px;font-weight:700;transition:.3s}
.close:hover,.close:focus{color:#bbb;text-decoration:none;cursor:pointer}
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {.modal-content{width:100%}}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/150/150" class="thumb">
  <div class="modal">
    <span class="close">
         &times;
      </span>
    <img class="modal-content">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/137/150/150" class="thumb">
  <div class="modal">
    <span class="close">
         &times;
      </span>
    <img class="modal-content">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here you go I rewrote everything to look a bit cleaner. Might wanna use `class` as `id`'s are specific to a element and `class` you can invoke multiple times.

```js
function showModal(src) {
  var modal = $("#myModal");
  var modalImg = $(".modal-content");

  $(".close").on("click", () => {
    modal.hide();
  });
  modalImg.prop('src', src);
  modal.show();
}

function loadImages() {

$(imgArr).each(function() {

    $('<img />').prop("src", this).appendTo("#myImages").addClass("myImg");
});
$(".myImg").on("click", (e) => {

        showModal($(e.currentTarget).prop("src"));
    });
}
var imgArr = ["https://picsum.photos/id/237/150/150", "https://picsum.photos/id/137/150/150"];
loadImages();
```

```css
    .myImg {
      border-radius: 5px;
      cursor: pointer;
      transition: 0.3s;
      display: block;
      margin-bottom: 5px; 
    }

    .myImg:hover {
      opacity: 0.7;
    }

    .modal {
      display: none;
      position: fixed;
      z-index: 1;
      padding-top: 100px;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      overflow: auto;
      background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    }

    .modal-content {
      margin: auto;
      display: block;
      width: 80%;
      max-width: 700px;
    }

    .modal-content,
    {
      animation-name: zoom;
      animation-duration: 0.6s;
    }

    @keyframes zoom {
      from {
        transform: scale(0)
      }
      to {
        transform: scale(1)
      }
    }

    .close {
      position: absolute;
      top: 15px;
      right: 35px;
      color: #f1f1f1;
      font-size: 40px;
      font-weight: bold;
      transition: 0.3s;
    }

    .close:hover,
    .close:focus {
      color: #bbb;
      text-decoration: none;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
      .modal-content {
        width: 100%;
      }
    }
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <span class="close">
         &times;
      </span>
    <img class="modal-content">
  </div>
  <div id="myImages"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```